# Is it "safe" to not have an ssl certificate if the web server I make calls to does

Tags: security, http, https

So for some background, I've been hosting a website on Microsoft Azure ("https://..."), and finally got a custom domain, but this domain does not have an ssl certificate.

Is it "safe" (I'm no expert in cyber security, so I'm sure its not as safe as possible, but is it at least pretty safe) to send password and other information from the unsecured domain to the azure server, which is still secured?

Comment: It is safer than normal HTTP, because the network traffic is encrypted. I suppose you use a self signed certificate. The Problem is that a user does not know that the certificate really belongs to that domain. The user could think that there is someone in between the connection -  maybe a man-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: Other important settings are the encryption ciphers your webserver offers. You should configure your server to only use strong cipher suites.

Comment: Have a look at let's encrypt. They offer free SSL cerificates.  https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

I would always say every website should have SSL and you can use Let's Encrypt - Free SSL/TLS Certificates https://letsencrypt.org/ its free

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a good reverse proxy, their SSL is the important one and should be CA verified. You can connect to them with self-signed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of your exact query. Are you looking not to buy a certificate or use the default azure secure domain for your login section.

The former letsencrypt is an awesome solution for a free certifcate. You definitely dont want to send password un encrypted.